# Placing a span after a div

Tags: html, css

I want to place a span next to div. Normally, it works fine but when I resize the browser and the div splits in two lines, the span goes to next line.

I have tried the "display:inline" property but it doesn't work.

`<div id="d1"> Welcome to HTML and CSS</div>
<span id ="cur">|</span>`

I expect the span to be placed right after the div when the div appears in two line because of browser resizing

Comment: The parent element will need some CSS. Do you already have any relevant CSS?

Comment: No sir the parent element has only margin in its css.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, Use `float:left;` to place span next to the div as shown below:

```html
<div id="d1" style="float: left;"> Welcome to HTML and CSS</div>
<span id ="cur">|</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The altered placement is due to the fact that the div is a block level element and the span is an inline level element. You could apply `display: inline` to the div, but I would use the ::after CSS pseudo selector and remove the span altogether.

Note that I have added a bit of filler text to your div to demonstrate the multiline layout.

The reason the line is placed after the text - instead of after the entire div, is that ::after pseudo elements are inserted as a last-child of the element that they are applied to - so in this case it is as if you are adding a "|" to the end of your text - within the div.

```css
#d1::after {
  content: '|';  
}
```

```html
<div id="d1"> Welcome to HTML and CSS. This is some more content to show the two lines. The line will be placed at the end of this div - so you don't need another span.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#cur{
  display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 248px) {
#d1{  
  display:inline-block;
  width:80%;
}
#cur{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="d1"> Welcome to HTML and CSS</div>
<span id ="cur">|</span>
```